# Do namespace aliases affect build times in large codebases? (C++)

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have some (not many) namespace aliases declared in headers. Some of the headers have pretty high visibility in a large codebase. I stopped using them for the most part years ago, but some still linger. I've also removed some of them along the way, but I did not time before/after. Before I go and remove them, I was wondering if anybody had tested and timed this, and what the results of that test were. I don't mind that they exist, unless they measurably hurt build times.

Comment: I very much doubt that adding/removing a few using directives would change the build time in a measurable way.

Comment: How much is your build time? I don't believe others' experience will be helpful much, since we know nothing about your project size and dependencies.

Comment: @avakar: `using` directives and `namespace aliases` are two very different things. The latter does not dump the whole content of a namespace in another.

Comment: @avakar name lookup consumes 6% of a build (here) with heavy optimization and high warning settings (each of which take a lot of time in their own right, which affects that percentage). also, namespace alias != `using namespace`.

Comment: @littleadv a full build produces about 1GB of linked and stripped binary for x86_64. reuse is high, and many of the programs are template heavy. build times are high, but i have not measured lately.

Comment: @littleadv perhaps a better measure would be 'it typically takes one or two minutes to get from the start of the build to launch'.

Comment: 1-2 minutes and you're worried? Man.... When I make a full build I can go, have lunch outside, come back and have some coffee before launch.

Comment: @littleadv sorry, i meant an incremental change+build+link to launch, not a full rebuild. a clean build of the primary root projects takes about 30 minutes (sleepy, forgot it was in the build logs).

Comment: @MatthieuM., right, sorry, namespace alias definition is what I meant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I can only speak from my limited experience with the clang compiler.

In clang, a namespace alias definition will not cause all symbols from the source namespace to be copied into the current declaration context (i.e. scope). Instead, the compiler will emit a [namespace alias declaration](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1NamespaceAliasDecl.html) record into the context.

In other words, the size of the symbol table is only increased by one and as such, lookups that don't name the alias are only marginally affected. Of course, if you use the alias, two lookups are performed -- one that locates the alias declaration and one that performs the lookup in the target namespace.

Comment: +1 thank you avakar. this details the complexity of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of namespace aliases is unlikely to affect your build time significantly, however the inclusion of superfluous headers certainly is.

A C++ compilation phase suffers greatly from all the IO it generates to get the content of the multiple include files that are scattered around the disk, eliminating a significant portion of those files should improve your build-time.

A corner case would be if you have heavy preprocessing/meta-programming code, in which case you might hit CPU/memory bandwidth bounds and the supplementary file won't matter much.

As a reminder, the best way to reduce compilation time is to eliminate dependencies so that incremental builds are smaller.

Comment: alright, thanks for your answer (+1). in my case, i've already done the obvious stuff to reduce build times here (unfortunately).